# Views pre execute

Tags: drupal

I want to alter some arguments from texonomy_term view.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_execute(&$view){
    if ($view->name == 'taxonomy_term') {

        $view->set_arguments(array(1)); // I want to change first arg to '1'

    }
}
```

But nothing works. On term page the result remains the same (default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to use hook_views_pre_view()

Comment: You can also use hook_views_pre_build. Sadly I didn't find a way to alter arguments than was send to the view. In those two hook $view->args is still empty.

Comment: what does view->pre_execute do vs view->execute?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need module code for that; you can specify in the Views UI that the first argument should default to 1 (or any other value).

Comment: 1 - it was just for example. The goal was another!

Comment: In that case, please consider asking the true question next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the default argument to '1' on the views argument section .